# Uncheck ToggleButton when other button is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, togglebutton

As per description, I have a `ToggleButton` and a `Button`.

The `Button` appears when the `ToggleButton` is toggled, and disappears when untoggled.

I would like to trigger the `ToggleButton` property `IsChecked` and set it to false when the `Button` is clicked. I know that it should be done with triggers but I can't figure out how.

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="EditBtn" VerticalAlignment="Top" Focusable="False">

<Button VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="24" Width="24" 
        Visibility="{Binding ElementName=EditBtn, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
        Command="{Binding ElementName=InfoList, Path=DataContext.SaveCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" >
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonTransparentStyle}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <!-- Something here? -->
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using StoryBoard:

```
<Button VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="24" Width="24" 
    Visibility="{Binding ElementName=EditBtn, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
    Command="{Binding ElementName=InfoList, Path=DataContext.SaveCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" >
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                        Storyboard.TargetName="EditBtn"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ToggleButton.IsChecked)">
                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame
                            KeyTime="00:00:00"
                            Value="False"/>
                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

You can also bind the IsChecked property of your ToggleButton, and just modify the attached property in your ViewModel (in the void triggered by your Button's Command).

Comment: Thanks for the solution. In the end I binded the IsChecked property. I would have liked to avoid it, but the xaml option is a workaround. So let be it.